# Is eigenspace based classification possible

Tags: classification, pca, eigenvalues

Imagine I would like to classify an image (e.g. into healthy and sick)
and have a lot of labeled data. Could I classify any image by comparing it to the eigenspaces of the two sets?

It sounds simple, but for some reason I haven't read about it.

One thing that worries me is that it could be hard to correctly match eigenvectors for comparissons.

[It seems like there are](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/karampatziakis14.pdf) [some papers on this](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/FLAIRS/2002/FLAIRS02-070.pdf)